# Upgraded from Pi2 to Pi3 - Internal wireless adapter isn't working

Tags: wireless, pi-3

I've bought my new Raspberry Pi 3, plugged it in, took my Raspberry Pi 2 SD Card with Raspbian installed on it.

Turned it on, everything is working great and faster than ever - but!

No wireless adapters are shown in the wpa-gui app\ifconfig, nor I can't connect to any network (kind of because of that).

I did able to get wireless from an **external** adapter and update&upgrade the system + I did rpi-update.

Nothing helped, I can't get the internal wireless to work.
Any ideas?

I'm using the RSElectronics PI, + Raspbian version of 4.1.18-v7+

Am I missing some drivers?
How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you do a `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` which should install needed drivers. You SHOULD NOT run `rpi-update` which is for beta testers only. If you already have working WiFi on the same network nothing more is needed.

Comment: So I did the dist-upgrade and now the bar has moved to the top (moved it back down ;P) . even though I can see it's the same version in uname and I do have some UI changes, no Wifi still.
I have an icon of 2 computers with an X. the wpa_supplicant.conf is configured well and ifconfig still doesn't show any wlan adapters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version doesnt contain the drivers.  I am sure an update will come along soon where they are included! (please note this applies to both NOOBS itself 1.8.0 and Raspian)

[A corroborating article](http://www.zdnet.com/article/more-hand-on-with-the-raspberry-pi-3-bluetooth-openelec-ubuntu-mate-and-more/)

UPDATE:
[Officially fixed](http://www.zdnet.com/article/raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-linux-and-noobs-distributions-updated/)

Comment: So how come that most people can use the internal Wifi without any issues?

Comment: added a link that corroborates.  Although true right now, I doubt it will be excluded for long

Comment: Hmm, so If I start from scratch, and reload the image to the SD card I will have the drivers, and if I'm upgrading I'l have to wait for the drivers?
Did I understood correctly?

Comment: Mine worked perfectly. I upgraded my Pi2 image (according to the recommended instructions) and inserted the card into the Pi3 and it worked. I did need to install bluetooth drivers (as explained in MagPi).